# Reallocation of Shared Memory

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, mmap

In order to reallocate shared memory I am currently using mremap to enlarge a particular shared memory size. The following is the statement that is being used in order to achieve this objective:

```
char *mem = (char*)mremap(addr, sizeof(addr), mem_range + 1, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);
```

Despite the inclusion of:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/mman.h>
```

Eclipse is showing that the `Symbol 'MREMAP_MAYMOVE' could not be resolved`.

However, given that eclipse is showing the above mentioned error, the code is being compiled.

The following shows this scenario:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show a full example program?  I imagine `sizeof(addr)` isn't what you want (it'll return the size of a pointer type if `addr` is a pointer to previously allocated memory).  It'd also be good to see the type of `mem_range`

Comment: The "could not resolve" error is from the linker telling you that it can't find the function in its library, and the "pointer from integer without a cast" is the compiler telling you that the function isn't prototyped in a header file. It sounds like the function just isn't on your system.

Comment: Don't paste images.  Paste text.

Comment: It's just the CDT parser not being able to resolve the symbol. if you add a symbol into the `C/C++ Build` -> `GCC C Compiler` -> `Symbols` has the `_GNU_SOURCE` variable defined, or `#include <linux/mman.h>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this problem, I simply had to include:
`#include <linux/mman.h>` instead of `#include <sys/mman.h>`

Apparently this was a bug in Ubuntu, referring to: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-plugins/+bug/1075718

Answer (score 1):

The following code compiles and links without errors or warnings on SuSE Linux SLES11:

---

```
gcc -Wall -o test test.c
```

---

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
   {
   void   *oldMapAddress = NULL;
   size_t  oldMapSize    = 512;
   size_t  newMapSize    = 1024;
   void   *newMapAddress = NULL;

   newMapAddress = mremap(oldMapAddress, oldMapSize, newMapSize, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);

   return(0);
   }
```

---

*The above code is not to be executed.  It only a compiler/linker proof.*

Comment: I definitely agree with your code. I have noticed that my source code was being compiled however eclipse, despite that is showing that the build was successful, it is showing the mentioned problems. I don't have any idea why this is happening.

Comment: Please refer to the above answer, sorry for any inconvenience caused but it was an Ubuntu bug!